# In javascript detect the "Window" part of [object Window]

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript detect the "Window" part of [object Window]  and/or tell if code is running on a node server or a browser

A litter more context. I'm writing a module for nodejs that is supposed to run on both the client and the server. I need to to differently in a couple places so I need to detect where it's running. right now I'm passing "this" to the init function which give me [object Object] on the server and [object Window] in browser. ... but I don't know how to check against the Window / Object part. typeof just seems to check the leading 'object' part. Thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you'll receive `[object Object]` in node.js and `[object Window]` in browser, then just check

```
var isBrowser = (this.toString().indexOf('Window') != -1);
var isServer = !isBrowser;
```

The `indexOf` method of a string checks for the position of its parameter in that string. Return value `-1` means the parameter is not present as a substring.

**Update**

As others have suggested to just check for the existence of the `window` object, you can equivalently check for other objects that you expect to be present in a browser, like `navigator` or `location`. However, this kind of check, that has been suggested above:

```
var isBrowser = (this.window == this);
```

will end up with a reference error in node.js. The correct way to do this is

```
var isBrowser = ('window' in this);
```

or, as I noted

```
var isBrowser = ('navigator' in this);
var isBrowser = ('location' in this);
```

Comment: Updated to reflect discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`[object Window]` is not reliable. Some older browsers just say `[object]` or `[object Object]` regardless of the type of object.

Try this instead:

```
var isBrowser = this instanceof Window;
```

Or, since I've never used Node.js, how about this?

```
var isBrowser = typeof Window != "undefined";
```

Comment: Of course, you'll want to check for the existence of `Window` first :) How about `this.window === this`?

Comment: This throws a `ReferenceError` in Node.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if you're running on Node, just see if `this === this.window`.

```
if (this === this.window) {
    // Browser
} else {
    // Node
}
```

This is more reliable than hoping that `toString`'s implementation is consistent, which it isn't.

Comment: If `process` isn't defined, you won't be able to check it with an `if`. Use `typeof process !== 'undefined'` or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I don't think you can beat:

```
if('window' in this) {
    // It's a browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are asking how to detect Node.js in your script =x

The following was modified and extended from Underscore.js, which i use a varient for some of my client/server module code too. It basically scans for global variables that are somewhat unique to node.js (unless you created them in client side =x)

This is to provide an alternative answer, in case it was all that was needed.

```
(function() {
    //this is runned globally at the top somewhere
    //Scans the global variable space for variables unique to node.js
    if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports && typeof require !== 'undefined' && require.resolve ) {
        this.isNodeJs = true;
    } else {
        this.isNodeJs = false;
    }
})();
```

Alternatively, if you want to call it only when needed

```
function isNodeJs() {
    //this is placed globally at the top somewhere
    //Scans the global variable space for variables unique to node.js
    if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports && typeof require !== 'undefined' && require.resolve ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```